# Different results between Cox regression models when using Surv in different ways?

Tags: r, cox-model

Why results are different between the two examples of Cox models where Surv was defined in different ways?

```
# ------------------------------- data
# -------------------------------

# id: identification number
# start and stop: start and end time points of a time interval
# event: 0-alive, 1-death

library("survival")
library("dplyr")
mydata<-heart%>%
  relocate(id,start,stop,event)%>%
  mutate(time=stop-start) # follow-up time

head(mydata)

  id start stop event        age      year surgery transplant time
1  1     0   50     1 -17.155373 0.1232033       0          0   50
2  2     0    6     1   3.835729 0.2546201       0          0    6
3  3     0    1     0   6.297057 0.2655715       0          0    1
4  3     1   16     1   6.297057 0.2655715       0          1   15
5  4     0   36     0  -7.737166 0.4900753       0          0   36
6  4    36   39     1  -7.737166 0.4900753       0          1    3

# ------------------------------ example 1
# ------------------------------ generate Surv first and then put it into coxph()

# create Surv object and then use it in the cox model
mydata$surset<-Surv(mydata$time,
                    mydata$event==1)

is.Surv(mydata$surset)

fit<-coxph(surset~transplant+age+surgery+year,data=mydata)
summary(fit)

Call:
coxph(formula = surset ~ transplant + age + surgery + year, data = mydata)

  n= 172, number of events= 75 

                coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
transplant1 -0.28292   0.75358  0.26314 -1.075   0.2823  
age          0.02819   1.02859  0.01386  2.034   0.0419 *
surgery     -0.66423   0.51467  0.36634 -1.813   0.0698 .
year        -0.15234   0.85870  0.07056 -2.159   0.0309 *

# ------------------------------ example 2
# ------------------------------ using Surv(start,stop,event==1) in coxph()
# use Surv object directly in the cox model
fit<-coxph(Surv(start,stop,event==1)~transplant+age+surgery+year,data=mydata)
summary(fit)

Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(start, stop, event == 1) ~ transplant + 
    age + surgery + year, data = mydata)

  n= 172, number of events= 75 

                coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
transplant1 -0.01025   0.98980  0.31375 -0.033   0.9739  
age          0.02717   1.02754  0.01371  1.981   0.0476 *
surgery     -0.63721   0.52877  0.36723 -1.735   0.0827 .
year        -0.14635   0.86386  0.07047 -2.077   0.0378 *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that data set, `transplant` is a time-varying predictor. That requires the 3-argument counting-process `Surv(startTime, stopTime, event)` form of a `Surv` object to model properly. See the R [time dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf).

When you set up your own 2-argument `Surv` object, you ignored the time-dependent nature of the `transplant` predictor. The model then assumed that each row represented a different individual whose corresponding `transplant` value had been in place for that individual since `time = 0`.

In reality, the patient with `id=4`, for example, had `transplant=1` only starting at `time = 36`, with `transplant=0` prior to that time. Your construction of the 2-argument `Surv` object set up that patient as two separate patients, one with `transplant=0` since `time=0` and no event at `time=36`, plus a patient with `transplant=1` since `time=0` and an event at `time=3`. That's not consistent with the data.